# html div parsing issue

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/css I need help which I have recorded in the screencast is well.
here is the link.
[Screencast video](http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbiOiKlxFJ)
I don't know exactly what am I missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax issue;

in css file, above `#wiggly`, there is extra `}`, delete it. It's going fix if you don't have another syntax issue.